# Belkin F7D1102 N150/Surf Micro Wireless Adapter- connectivity problems

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10, realtek

The network manager keeps prompting me for a password, while i'm sure it's correct. Sometimes it connects for a minute. When i used windows 8 at the same place with the same router, i didn't have this connection problems. Apparently someone has filed a bug already (http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1244408?comments=all).

As stated in the title the model my Belkin wifi adapter is F7D1102 N150/Surf Micro with RTL8188CUS chipset (more information about device) http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Belkin_F7D1102. I'm using a recently updated Kubuntu 13.10 installation.

When i type `lsusb` and `lsmod` in the terminal, i got the following output:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 050d:1102 Belkin Components F7D1102 N150/Surf Micro Wireless    Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

Module                  Size  Used by
rtl8192cu              67723  0 
rtl_usb                18448  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                63229  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        48877  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              596969  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              479757  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep firmware` gives:

```
[   61.782478] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
```

I tried several solutions to my connection problems:

### Compilation of driver provided by Realtek:

I searched for the RTL8188CUS driver on Realtek's website and tried to compile it myself using the install script. When executing the script, `sudo make driver`fills my screen with a repeating error: `implicit declaration of function`?

### Installation of Windows drivers on CD with nsdiswrapper

Blacklisted original driver. Windows driver doesn't work.

---

### (Solution) Patched version of original driver (Ubuntu 13.10)

Meanwhile I found at that someone has patched the original rtl8192cu driver [link](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P. Varet has patched the Realtek driver for Ubuntu 13.10: [link](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)

### Installation (from site)

Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

Clone this repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install it:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

And reboot. You're done.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
```

...means that the required firmware was found and loaded; there is no problem there. And this:

```
Er is geen regel om doel 'Driver
```

...means that 'make' doesn't work on files with spaces in them, like this:

```
/home/willem/Bureaublad/Network Driver/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
```

Please rename the folder Network_Driver instead of Network Driver. I suspect it will then compile correctly. However, it is probably not the preferred way to install a different driver. What troubles are you having that made you decide to abandon a working driver and firmware package?

Comment: I didn't have as much connectivity problems in windows 8 with the same router and adapter. Thanks for your fast response.